# Return struct from function?

Tags: c

I have a problem over here

```
typedef struct
{
  int hours;
  int minutes;
  int seconds; 
} Time;

Time calcTime(Time time1, Time time2)
{
    Time calc1;
    Time calc2;

    calc1.hours - calc2.hours;

    return calc1; // How do I print this outside the function?
}
```

How do I print **calc1.seconds** OUTSIDE the function?

Comment: `OUTSIDE the function?` You cannot. You have to print the value in some function where the value is returned. You did not fix your code even after getting answers? SO is not an online debugger for C.

Comment: You are leaking memory there...The structure is out of scope as soon as the function is finished. Declare the structure outside and pass it by reference as a parameter!

Comment: @opalenzuela - There is no memory leak and returning structs is safe.

Comment: `calc1` and `calc2` contain garbage, and the line `calc1.hours - calc2.hours` has no effect.

Comment: Accessing uninitialised variables provokes undefined behaviuor. After this anything can happen.

Answer (score 5):

This is how you can do it.

```
Time t = calcTime(time1, time2);
printf("%d %d %d\n", t.hours, t.minutes, t.seconds);
```

However, please use `time_t`, `struct tm` from `time.h` for any time related implementation.
You can find more information [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/) or an example [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Time-Functions-Example.html).

There are some fixes required in `calcTime`

```
Time calcTime(Time calc1, Time calc1)
{
    // Do not re declare the function arguments.
    //Time calc1;
    //Time calc2;

    // This has no effect, unless you store the result
    // calc1.hours - calc2.hours;
    calc1.hours -= calc2.hours;   // short for calc1.hours = calc1.hours - calc2.hours

    // you need to also check if hours has a valid value after the operation
    if(calc1.hours < 0 || calc1.hours > 24) {
        // error
    }

    return calc1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Even if you call the function it will not work because you are subtracting uninitialized variables. You do not need `time1` and `time2` in `calcTime`, instead just define your function like this:

```
Time calcTime(Time calc1, Time calc2)
{
    //Time calc1;
    //Time calc2;

    // calc1.hours - calc2.hours; --> You are not storing the value here    

    calc1.hours -= calc2.hours; // or you should write --> calc1.hours = calc1.hours - calc2.hours

    return calc1; 
}
```

And call in `main`:

```
int main()
{
    Time t1,t2;
    t1.hours = 10;
    t2.hours = 5;
    t2 = calcTime(t1, t2);
    printf("The time is %d hours", t2.hours);
}
```

Comment: good point, didn't even notice his function was doing nothing.

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia - Yeah - this fella had already asked a similar question - but still did not fix his/her code. Wonder if our answers will help.

Answer (score 1):

Just call into the function (also note I changed your function to actually return a relevant value).

```
typedef struct
{
  int hours;
  int minutes;
  int seconds; 
} Time;

Time calcTime(Time calc1, Time calc2)
{
    calc1.hours = calc1.hours - calc2.hours;

    return calc1;
}

int main()
{
    Time t1;
    Time t2;
    t1.hours = 10;
    t2.hours = 5;
    Time t3 = calcTime(t1, t2);
    printf("The time is %d hours", t3.hours);
}
```